# Osclass search from homepage to search for location also

Tags: search, osclass

I am trying to configure osclass for a real estate website. when searching from the home page, i need the search keywords to be searched in city and region too... ie, if the search key is "apartment newyork", all apartments where city or region is newyork should be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the city filter  try this one

```
<?php $aCities = City::newInstance()->listAll(); ?>
<?php if(count($aCities) > 0 ) { ?>
<select name="sCity" id="sCity">
<option value=""><?php _e('Select a city...')?></option>
<?php foreach($aCities as $city) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $city['s_name'] ; ?>">
<?php echo $city['s_name'] ; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```